# Como leer un archivo separado por comas y guardar datos en un arreglo de estructuras en C?

Tags: c, csv

Tengo un archivo separado por comas. Quiero leer cada linea y guardar los datos en un arreglo de "structs".Dentro de un "while loop", uso fscanf() a fin de  leer cada linea del archivo. Asimismo, dentro del mismo ciclo, uso strtok() para devidir cada dato separado por coma y guardarlo dentro de la posisición "i" del arreglo.
Al imprimir, el arreglo, fuera del while loop obtengo un resultado inesperado:

```
// este es mi archivo separado por comas
juan,1,19
pepe,2,22
chucho,3,18
```

```
while(j<3){
    printf("%s %i %i \n", arreglo[j].name, arreglo[j].id, arreglo[j].age);
    j++;
}
//resultado esperado:
//juan,1,19
//pepe,2,22
//chucho,3,18

//resultado obtenido:
//chucho,1,19
//chucho,2,22
//chucho,3,18
```

El problema es que el primer dato de la ultima linea se guarda en todos los elementos del arreglo en su propiedad "name".

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <string.h>

struct Student{
    char *name;
    int id;
    int age;
};

void inicio(){

int i =0, j=0;
Student *arreglo = new Student[3];
char line[50];
FILE  *file;
file = fopen("students.csv", "r");

if(file == NULL){
        printf("could not open file");
        return;
    }
char name[20], idChar[10], ageChar[10];
int id, age;


while(i<3){

        //guardar linea del archivo en variable linea
        fscanf(file,"%s", line); 
        //dividir la linea y guardar datos en variable 
        strcpy(name, strtok(line, ","));
        strcpy(idChar, strtok(NULL, ","));
        strcpy(ageChar, strtok(NULL, ","));
        //convertir idChar y ageChar en enteros
        sscanf(idChar, "%d",&id);
        sscanf(ageChar, "%d",&age);
        //guardar variables en arreglo de estructuras
        arreglo[i].name = name;
        arreglo[i].id = id;
        arreglo[i].age = age;
       

    i++;

}

//verificar que el arreglo tiene las posiciones y los valores correctos
while(j<iMax){
    printf("%s %i %i \n", arreglo[j].name, arreglo[j].id, arreglo[j].age);
    j++;
}
//resultado esperado:
juan,1,19
pepe,2,22
chucho,3,18
//resultado obtenido:

chucho,1,19
chucho,2,22
chucho,3,18
}

#endif // PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: `new` es un operador de C++. ¿Seguro que esto es C? Si realmente es C, deberías usar [`malloc`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene sentido que imprima el mismo nombre para los 3. Porque estás copiando el string leído al arreglo `name` y luego haces que el puntero `name` de cada elemento apunte a `name`:

```
arreglo[i].name = name;
```

Para que esto no pase, debes guardar los nombres en diferentes regiones de memoria.

Por ejemplo puedes reservar memoria. Así:

```
arreglo[i].name = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(arreglo[i].name, name);
```

O incluso puedes copiar el nombre directamente al bloque que acabas de reservar:

```
arreglo[i].name = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(arreglo[i].name, strtok(line, ","));
```

Por cierto, en lugar de una cantidad constante puedes reservar solo lo necesario. Si vas a usar la misma capacidad para todos los nombres mejor define el struct así:

```
struct Student{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int age;
};
```

De este modo no tienes que reservar memoria 2 veces (una para la estructura y otra para el nombre).

---

Por cierto, el código que escribiste claramente es de C++, solo que es compatible con C y puedes usar funciones de éste. En C:

- No existe el operador `new`.
- Para declarar una variable de tipo `struct` necesitas escribir `struct` antes. Por ejemplo:

  struct Estudiante estudiante1;

Por lo tanto, sugiero que te decantes por funciones de la [librería estándar de C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library).

- Para almacenar cadenas de texto usa [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).
- Para abrir, leer y escribir archivos usa [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).
- Para leer una línea usa [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).
- Para buscar una cadena en un `string` puedes usar [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).
- Para convertir a tipos numéricos también existen [funciones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).
- O incluso puedes leer un tipo numérico directamente del archivo con el [operador `>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).